# GPS Data Preprocessing Recommandations?

Tags: data-mining, data, preprocessing, geospatial

**GPS Data Preprocessing**

I got  gps traces of busses which traveled from one place (bus station) to another. This file contains relevant(eg:- Data recorded between the starting bus station and ends with the destination stop) and irrelevant GPS traces(eg- traces recorded from bus station to the home of the bus driver). All the data of the month is in the same file. Looking for a efficient preprocessing technique **to separate journeys** from the file. The data fields in the files are **"timestamp", "lat","lon"**.  Can somebody suggest any techniques for this preprocessing step?

Comment: How do you yourself know which trace is relevant?

Comment: @Dahn relevant traces are the traces which are recorded between the Origin and destination. example of non related ones would be "Driver's home location to Origin station".